# How to stream video file to RTMP server with gstreamer on RPI2

Tags: pi-2, streaming-video

I've been trying for hours to set up the pipeline for streaming an MP4 file to nginx via RTMP on my rpi2.

- must use Openmax GPU encoding (omxh264enc)

Here's the command I'm trying

```
gst-launch-1.0 \
  filesrc location="/path/to/video.mp4" ! decodebin name=t \
  t. ! videoconvert ! omxh264enc ! queue ! flvmux name=mux \
  t. ! audioconvert ! voaacenc bitrate=128000 ! queue ! mux. \
  mux. ! rtmpsink location="rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/cantelope live=1"
```

which outputs

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstOMXH264Enc-omxh264enc:omxh264enc- omxh264enc0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
gstomxvideoenc.c(865): gst_omx_video_enc_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstOMXH264Enc-omxh264enc:omxh264enc-omxh264enc0:
stream stopped, reason not-negotiated
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Edit: This is the new command and output.

Comment: The standard RPi hardware does not have any audio **input** capabilities and it looks as though that command expects to get its audio from a local device and not from presumably where it should (a file or pipe?)

Comment: @SlySven You're right of course, and I think I fixed the audio part, but I'm getting a new error now. See edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was getting the same error and found the following test pipeline to work:

`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! omxh264enc ! "video/x-h264,profile=high" ! h264parse ! matroskamux ! filesink location=output.avi`

This was based on an old thread on the raspberrypi.org forums at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=34250&start=75 by by Defiant on Sun Nov 17, 2013 7:22 pm

I modified the pipeline from my Logitech QuickCam Pro 9000 as follows resulting in success.

`gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! image/jpeg,width=960,height=720,framerate=15/1 ! jpegdec ! omxh264enc ! "video/x-h264,profile=high" ! h264parse ! matroskamux ! filesink location=output.mkv`

My system is a Raspberry Pi 2
Linux carpi 4.1.13-v7+ #826 SMP PREEMPT Fri Nov 13 20:19:03 GMT 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux

```
gst-inspect-1.0 omxh264enc
Factory Details:
  Rank                     primary + 1 (257)
  Long-name                OpenMAX H.264 Video Encoder
  Klass                    Codec/Encoder/Video
  Description              Encode H.264 video streams
  Author                   Sebastian Dröge <sebastian.droege@collabora.co.uk>

Plugin Details:
  Name                     omx
  Description              GStreamer OpenMAX Plug-ins
  Filename                 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstomx.so
  Version                  1.0.0.1
  License                  LGPL
  Source module            gst-omx
  Source release date      2015-11-11 17:35 (UTC)
  Binary package           GStreamer OpenMAX Plug-ins git
  Origin URL               Unknown package origin
```

Comment: I was able to modify my command with the info provided in this answer, and got it working. Thank you!

Comment: the ! h264parse ! pipeline element was required for me, which I found in the gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad debian package.